# preventing from deal lock and race condition in sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, deadlock, race-condition

i have one stored procedure like this:

```
{
delete from outbox where status=1         // delete previous sent record
update outbox set status=1 where ....     // flag some record
select from outbox where status=1         // select them for send
}
```

multiple thread call this Stored procedure and dead lock occurs.
1. is there any solution to release lock between each query in store procedure?
or 
2. prevent concurrent execution of SP (SPs)?

thanks

Comment: do it in batches......

Comment: Plan your locking properly. Hints can avoid locks. As can tx isolation level. You have control - you just do not use it. This is SQL basics....

Comment: If you specify a specific item in your outbox to be deleted and updated, and specify a `WITH (NOLOCK)` in your select you should have better results. But you cannot run deletes and updates as general as that and hope not to get dead locks

Answer (score 0):

if u want to prevent concurrent execution of **SP** then there is a way. use what is known as [SQL Server Application locks.](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/01/08/Application-Locks-or-Mutexes-in-SQL-Server-2005.aspx)

You can also go through this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933410%28SQL.80%29.aspx) too